# jqGrid ondblclickevent not being called

Tags: javascript, jquery, jqgrid

I'm trying to add a function to the `jqgrid ondblclick` function but i am trying to attach this event in a `JavaScript` file so it will be attached to all the grids, but when I go to double click the row nothing happens at all.

Here is my code:

```
$(function () {
                            var grid = jSnap.grids.createGrid($("#productSetStockSearchList"));

                            $(grid.grid).on('jqgridondblClickRow', function (id) {
                                    var rowData = $(this).getRowData(id);
                                    jSnap.modals.openModal({ action: "StockDetails", controller: "Stock", itemId: rowData.StockId, width: 800, height: 600 })
                            });
});
```

What is the function name for `jqgridondblClickRow`?

Answer (score 1):

It should be

```
$(function () {
                            var grid = jSnap.grids.createGrid($("#productSetStockSearchList"));

                            $(grid.grid).on('ondblClickRow:', function (id) {
                                    var rowData = $(this).getRowData(id);
                                    jSnap.modals.openModal({ action: "StockDetails", controller: "Stock", itemId: rowData.StockId, width: 800, height: 600 })
                            });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Its ok, i had to change the name "jqgridondblClickRow" to "jqGridDblClickRow" here is the fixed code

```
$(function () {
                            var grid = jSnap.grids.createGrid($("#productSetStockSearchList"));

                            $(grid.grid).on('jqGridDblClickRow', function (e, id) {
                                var rowData = $(this).getRowData(id);
                                jSnap.modals.openModal({ action: "StockDetails", controller: "Stock", itemId: rowData.StockId, width: 800, height: 675 });
                            });
});
```